# Database Design :: Normalization in 2 Participant Event :: Join Table or 2 Column?

Tags: database-design, normalization

**Edit**: updating generalized question to reflect actual domain: sport of hockey.

The actual event then is a games schedule, and the participants are teams.

Teams are the ultimate "owners" (i.e. when team deleted so should any related scheduled games, results, players, and player stats).

The problem discussed so far in this thread covers the decision to combine an event into a single row with 2 columns (team1, team2) or to break out into a join table.  The consensus so far is: stay with 2 column approach. However, given that the original question applied to generic events and not scheduled games WITH related results, there may be a change in the approach (for example, some might say that the game schedule should record BOTH schedule info [date, time, location, teams] and game outcome/result info (score, win-loss-tie, penalty minutes power plays, etc.) and therefore a join table should be added to generate unique gameIDs).

Responses so far have been excellent ;--)  Will flag as answered pending any updates.  Thanks everyone!

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

---

Puzzled over how to solve this problem.

What is the normalized approach to handling an event (taking place on given date & location) where there will always be exactly 2 participants?

The non-normalized approach would be to create an events table:

1) eventID PK (autonum)
2) two columns, participant1 & participant2, PKs (autonum) from a participants table.

While this approach does consolidate event creation in a single table record (no join table to create eventIDs), one problem with this design is that technically participants should be the owning side of the equation; i.e. when deleting a participant, any related event should be deleted since orphaned events are not allowed.

The alternative, a join table, would as I see it generate a unique eventID along with date, time, and location. The revised events table would then consist of the join table eventID and 2 separate rows, one for each participant.  With this approach I can easily add an FK to the events table for participantID (PK from participants table) and thereby have proper constraints in place.

How would you approach this problem? I should point out that we have been using the non-normalized design in production for a couple of years without issue (data constraints pushed to code level), but we are looking re-architect from the ground (Database) up (Code), thus the question ;--)

---

Comment: What's the new version?  I can merge this into it.  Also, please don't put tags in your title, kthx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think that's not normalised? Both participant IDs depend on the event in a way that makes it 3NF (depending on the key, the whole key and nothing but the key, so help me, Codd).

However, if the date and location also depend on the event ID, they too should be placed in this table (with perhaps the location being a foreign key lookup to another table, similar to the participants). Something akin to:

```
Events:
    EventId           primary key
    Date
    LocationId        references Locations(LocationId)
    ParticipantOneId  references Participants(ParticipantId)
    ParticipantTwoId  references Participants(ParticipantId)
Locations:
    LocationId        primary key
    <<Other location stuff>>
Participants:
    ParticipantId        primary key
    <<Other participant stuff>>
```

Just because you have something that *looks* like an array, that doesn't *automatically* violate 3NF, it's just a warning sign that should be looked at.

Now, if you ever discovered an event that could have 0, 1, 3 or greater participants, then you'd want to rework the schema.

Until then, YAGNI.

Comment: @Sweko, I'd prefer to be voted up for the quality of the answer rather than humour shamelessly stolen from elsewhere but, hey, I'll take rep as it comes :-)

Comment: +1 @pax yes, date & location are in the same table. Don't get me wrong, I like the existing design, but have always had this nagging thought, can't this be improved upon? The bane of a hacker, improvement, you might be right with the YAGNI comment...

Comment: I gave @pax the nod here, all the answers were good in there own way, but pax cleared up a misconception I had about normalization as it relates to the 2 column approach in a 1-to-2 relationship

Answer (score 2):

1. Take the constraints back out of application code and put them where they belong--under control of the dbms.
2. ID numbers have nothing to do with normalization.
3. You need a table of participants. Set foreign keys referencing participants from the table of events with `ON DELETE CASCADE`; that will let the dbms delete events when users delete one of the participants. This has a lot to do with data integrity, but nothing at all to do with normalization.

Comment: I tend to disagree with point 1. Multiple headaches can appear when using DB FK constraints - when you have to modify the table, to rename it, etc, while the business logic at application level has to be implemented anyway for CRUD operations. Those are good as a safety belt, but in my opinion its kind of an expensive one

Comment: @catcall, generally speaking yes, FK on delete cascade is my rule of thumb for parent-to-child tables.  I should update the question to reflect actual domain (sport: hockey). In this particular case I did not think of teams (participants) as the owning side as I was focused on the game schedule (events) as related to game results, where of course I do have on delete cascade. I'll be adding FKs for team1, team2 columns today to address the missing constraint between teams and schedules games. Thanks

Comment: @VirtualEyes: Also add the constraint that hometeam <> visitor. No sense in letting a team play itself.

Comment: @cat already in place, there's a unique constraint on team1 + team2 + gameDate

Comment: @Tudor Constantin: The alternative to dbms-controlled constraints is to let every application programmer reimplement all or part of it 100% correctly, every time they fire up their editor, from the day they first walk through the door until the company goes out of business. Odds are good that will fail. The database will long outlive your application code.

Comment: Yes, but having the constraint handled (correctly) only by the db and not by the app is not looking safe either

Comment: @Tudor Constantin: You said FK constraints declared to the dbms were an expensive safety belt, not really necessary because the app logic had to be implemented anyway. I never said app logic shouldn't be implemented. I said the dbms is the only software that can guarantee FK integrity.

Comment: agree on that - I think this could be a whole subject for debate

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2450/what-are-the-arguments-against-or-for-putting-application-logic-in-the-database-l/2457#2457

Answer (score 1):

Can you detail the other option you're proposing?  Or is that what you're asking for?  Without knowing all of the tables it is hard to say, but I think the way you're doing it is fine, especially since it is always a 1-to-2 relationship (game to teams).  Index by your IDs (gameId, teamId, etc.) and you'll be good and won't need to go through and refactor just for the sake of it.

Consider, the following, what advantage do you really get?

```
games
=========
game_id PK
game_date
game_time
location

games2teams <-- possibly overkill, since this is a 1-to-2, not 1-to-N or M-to-N
===========    
game_id
team_id

schools
==========
team_id
player_name

results
==========
game_id
team_id
score
```

Comment: yes, it's what I'm asking -- what makes a game unique is 2 participant teams playing each other on a given date-time. A join table would effectively be a gameID generator; composite table would then have 2 rows, one for each team, with gameID column as FK to join table. Not sure how much we'll gain in that setup (not to mention date-time, and location fields will be repeated)

Comment: just saw your update.  Hmmm, in that design, as you say, not sure how much is gained. I guess there's no way around the 1-2 relationship, adds a layer of complexity by nature of the constraint itself (i.e. 2 teams play one game). Just so you know the object graph, it's schools > teams > players > stats (scoring and goaltending), and teams > composite schedule > results

Answer (score 1):

Both your schemas are normalized, in the case that there will always be two and exactly two participants for each event.

I'd rather go with the approach that does not use a relationship table, and will set FK's on the Participant1 & Participant2 fields, to ensure proper integrity.

Comment: +1, right I actually attempted to add FKs yesterday on existing events table but failed (must have some orphaned event records preventing the FKs from being created).  I'll try against empty tables, should be fine, thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a m-to-n relationship (one person could create/participate to multiple events, to an event could be more participants), thus you should have 3 tables:

Table **events**:

- **id** - PK - autoincrement
- other details (start date, duration, location, etc)

Table **people**:

- **id** - PK - autoincrement
- other details

Table **person_event** :

- **id** - PK - autoincrement (this is a surrogate PK, needed because table holds supplementary information beside the person and event)
- **event_id** - FK on events
- **person_id** - FK on people
- **participant_role** - this can be organizer, simple participant, honoured guest, etc

Now, you can have as many participants to an event as you want, you can have multiple creators of the event, you can have as many roles as you want, enforcing whatever business logic you/the client need

Comment: This allows events to have multiple two-participant groupings (including zero) so it's more flexible but I'm not certain that was the intent of the question. It seemed to indicate and event would only _ever_ have _exactly_ two. But, I may have misunderstood - it wouldn't be the first time :-)

Comment: an event has exactly 2 participants, always a 1-to-2 relationship, which is why we originally went with the 2 column approach (if it were truly 1-to-many then multi column would be a terrible idea). I'm going to play around with a multi-table approach just to see how it affects code level vs. the single table design we have right now. Thanks for the feeback!

Comment: @paxdiablo - Yes, it seems I passed too fast over the part with 'there will always be exactly 2 participants' - in this case I agree that your solution is perfectly good (thumbs up)

Comment: You said, "this is a surrogate PK, needed because table holds supplementary information beside the person and event". You don't need a surrogate id number in order to store information besides person and event.

Comment: @pax, you are correct, event has exactly 2 participants.  Should note that the event is a scheduled game and the participants are teams, so game results are tied directly to the event schedule.  Game results table has 2 records, one for each team (score, win-loss-tie, penalties, powerplays, etc.)

Comment: @Catcall - you're right - its not 'needed' - but when the pivot table can be a resource on its own, in my opinion is better to be able to identify it by a single information - the surrogate PK

Comment: @Tudor Constantin: If the table is {event_id, p_1, p_2}, and event_id is the primary key, then you can access the row by the single column event_id. This, too, has nothing to do with normalization. (In case others might be confused about this point.)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you were wanting to keep data on the stats of players on both sides of the game but assumed you do. Also assumed that possible locations is not defined and not particularly important so just have a text field in the game entity to store this.  If you do want to **report** on events **by location** then you should add a location entity so you can book a game to a particular location from a list.
Here is a basic ER model that I think covers all your stated rules. It should help you arrive at a more detailed schema.
The "Diary" or log entity stores misc unstructured content about the game. e.g. "It was a rainy day and one player was sent off in the 9th minute.  blah.. blah..."

[image]

Comment: @user212... I'm going to open a new thread as pertains to team > schedule > results > players > stats, which was not part of the original question (to be fair those who already replied).  Will be under something like "Composite Game Schedule Normalization" (or look for post by user: virtualeyes). Will do in a bit, have to step away from computer.  Thanks for the reply!